# Is there a way to fix when I reload the current page in the browser after I click the next button it works like the next button?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a program where I'm going through tabs by clicking input submit buttons by pressing  next or previous. My problem is when I click next it go to the next page and I click to reload the page up in the browser box it it basically go the the next page without me pressing next when I just want to reload the page here is my code for my page action for Next.

```
app_xval = session("app_xval")


if app_xval="X" then
   upl.upload
   upl.MaxFileSize = 50000000
   page_action = upl.form("btnAction")
   has_setup   = upl.form("has_setup")
end if

if page_action = "Next" then

   app_pg = app_pg + 1
   session("app_pg") = app_pg

end if

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary me-2" name="btnAction" value="Next">
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: @user1599011 I don't get that

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: @user1599011 the reload this page at the top of the browser window I don't want to press that and it basically do what my next button do. I just want to reload the current page that I'm on. So what I mean is If I press Next it go to the next page so  when I click reload this page at the top it go to another page

Comment: .To reload the current page on clicking a buton ( as per your question title), you can use javascript as @user1599011 pointed out. If, as per your question body you need to prevent the page from going to the next on a reload, you might need to change the way the next button works, you might need to navigate depending on the page number instead of the page action.

Comment: @Flake can you give me an example please for the body question

Comment: Need to see the code for the next button

Comment: @Flakes attached above

Comment: This will be a hack :). Add a hidden input in the form:  `<input type="hidden" name="nextpage" value="<%=app_pg + 1%>">`. And in the processing code, inside the `if page_action = "Next" then` check  remove the `app_pg = app_pg + 1` , change `session("app_pg") = app_pg` to `session("app_pg") = upl.form("nextpage")`. Should work. Essentially, you need to remove that  `app_pg = app_pg + 1` part from the processing part.

Comment: @Flakes it work but now I have to click my next button twice so it can go to the next screen

Comment: What if you change the value of the hidden input to `session("app_pg")+1` instead of `app_pg+1`?

Comment: @Flakes  didn't work

Comment: @Flakes should I add some to my next button ?

Comment: Had a rethink: after adding the new hidden field, the only change you might need in the precessing part should be replacing the `app_pg = app_pg + 1` with `app_pg = Cint(upl.form("nextpage"))` .  Everything else remains the same. See if that works. (In your code you are getting all the form values within the `if app_xval="X" then` check, maybe you should get the value of the hidden field within that block into a variable and use it. You have all the code in front of you, please analyze and adjust.

Comment: @Flakes I have a question